# Prisma schema - Build up a custom object from a relation

Tags: next.js, schema, prisma, t3

Can I build a custom object using a relation, and the properties that it references?

For example, if I have two models like this, where User is populated during authentication:

```
model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
}

model Post {
  id          String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title       String
  description String
  authorId    String
  authorEmail String
  authorName  String
  user        User     @relation(fields: [authorId, authorEmail, authorName], references: [id, email, name])
}
```

This will take the user details and push them, individually, into authorId, authorName and authorEmail. What I would like is some way of loading them into an embedded document called author, like so:

```
model Post {
  id          String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title       String
  description String
  author      Author
  user        User     @relation(fields: [author], references: [id, email, name])
}

type Author {
  id    String
  name  String
  email String
}
```

Is this at all possible? I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: The post only needs to contain the `User` foreign key, so only `authorId`. `authorName` and `authorEmail` are unnecessary as you can get them from the post’s `user`

Comment: But to create a relation, I have to have a fields property, right? And so I have to have a references property. How do I get access to everything the User has to offer?

Comment: You can write something like `const post = await prisma.post.findUnique({ where: ..., include: { user: true } })`. Then you can access the user using `post.user`